# MS Access SQL Too Few Parameters: Expected 2

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

In MS Access 2010, I have the following query which randomly orders the data and puts it in a new sheet.  Before I added in the WHERE, it was working, but now I get an error telling me:

> Too few parameters: Expected 2.

Does anybody know how I could fix this?

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT [My_Sheet].* " & _
             " INTO My_New_Sheet" & _
             " FROM [My_Sheet] " & _
             " WHERE [Some_Field] = [Some_Possible_Value_For_The_Field] " & _
             " ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*[Some_Other_Field])*Time())"

Debug.Print sqlQuery
CurrentDb.Execute sqlQuery
```

Where `[Some_Possible_Value_For_The_Field]` is comes from `[My_Sheet]`

Note that this is Access SQL

Comment: Where are you expecting `[Some_Possible_Value_For_The_Field]` to come from? Does `[Some_Field]` exist in your table?

Comment: Yes, `[Some_Field]` does exist.  also, `[Some_Possible_Value_For_The_Field]` is expected to come from `[My_Sheet]`

Comment: *Where `[Some_Possible_Value_For_The_Field]` is expected to come from `[My_Sheet]`*: What does that mean?  Does that field exist in the table or not?

Comment: What is *My_Sheet* -a table? A form? A query?

Comment: Show your actual SQL - are you doing this in MS-Access or referencing MS-Excel data somehow. Your details are so minimal you can't expect an answer. What "new sheet" are you referring to? Most Access data sources are called tables

Comment: If the query was working before adding the WHERE clause then it seems pretty clear to me that the (linked?) table [My_Sheet] simply does not contain *columns* named [Some_Possible_Value_For_The_Field] and [Some_Other_Field]. Please [edit] your question to provide a better explanation of what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: When MS Access doesn't recognise a field name it assumes it's a parameter. So thats two field names it doesn't recognise and assumes they are parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sqlQuery = "SELECT [My_Sheet].* " & _
             " INTO My_New_Sheet" & _
             " FROM [My_Sheet] " & _
             " WHERE [Some_Field] = '" & [Some_Possible_Value_For_The_Field] & "'"  & _
             " ORDER BY Rnd(-(100000*" & [Some_Other_Field] & ")*Time())"

Debug.Print sqlQuery
CurrentDb.Execute sqlQuery
```

When you use a form variable, the value has to be read from outside of the SQL statement. Hence why we close the statement with double quote, add the field value, and then continue by opening the with a double quotes again.

Notice that you need to keep the field qualifiers. In this case I assumed your first field was a string which requires the single quote qualifiers and the second variable as an integer which doesn't require qualifiers.